# (Java) How to create an array with size based on user input, and also fill it with random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

This is the first part of a a school assignment.
I am not allowed to use ArrayList, Vector, or any other similar Java-class.

I'm supposed to have a user input how many random numbers will be generated, and then the program shall create an array with that amount of random numbers in it, and print those numbers out.

I know how to create arrays, and how to put things into them, but I've been hitting my head against the wall of creating this specific kind of array.
I know I can't create an array and then change the size of it once it already exists.

Grateful for any kind of hints or flat out explanations on how to accomplish this, as I've been sitting with this for 3 days now with no idea of how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to give you EVERYTHING, but I gave you alot. I hope this helps you understand, all you need now is to look at how to generate random numbers.

```
//This segment of code will take a number as input
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = input.nextInt();

//this will initialize the array
int[] arr = new int[num];

//this will let you initialize every element in array
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

 {randomized number code}

}
```

Comment: Many thanks~ 

I think I'll be able to figure out the rest based on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter array length: ");
int[] arr = new int[in.nextInt()];

Random random = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] = random.nextInt(100);   // random from 0 to 99 inclusive
```